# What would be the impacts on a town if the people did not need to eat or drink

Tags: society, economy

I am designing a town that upon entering you would no longer need to consume and food or water, you would just be "replenished" by magical or technological means without having to actually do anything. You never got hungry or thirsty and you had energy as if you were normally consuming food or water.

I am guessing that this type of thing would attract a lot of nobility and the rich, but i would also imagine it would attract beggars from all over since their worry of starvation is gone.

So as my title asks. What other major changes would come to this society?

Comment: What is the purpose of the place to begin with? Why not a place where  sirloin and fine wine appear on the dinner table every night? To me, eating/cooking is a part of culture that people would not give up even if we didn't need it. I understand how a bunch of bums could benefit, but I'm assuming there would be some kind of parameter for who can enter based on the reason for creating it in the first place?

Comment: Well its based off the Numenera world, so its from a past civilization, no one knows why it was originally built. People discovered this area that had some visible markers to outline its perimeter and they decided to build a city in it.

Comment: I find it less likely that the rich would be attracted there. When you have the luxury of eating whatever you want it becomes a leisure activity. They want fine dining and the taste...why would anyone go there except those too poor (or possibly too busy) to regard food as a luxury?

Comment: Do people still need to use the toilet?

Comment: I feel like this is verging on "too broad".

Comment: Reminds me of Log Horizon: all food (no matter what it was) replenished hunger the same amount and tasted like wet cardboard. No flavor, no texture, bland tasteless nothing. But it kept you alive. So everyone was buying the cheapest food they could (say, `$`5 / day) which required the meagerest of adventuring (every goblin slain dropped `$`1 and would respawn in an hour). The main town looked like the slums as everyone grew super depressed and listless. (Edit: why is LaTeX enabled in comments..?)

Comment: @Draco18s MathJax is enabled in comments because it's an all-or-nothing thing, and it is sufficiently useful on our site to warrant having it turned on. We've had MathJax since Oct 2014. https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/90/29 You need to backslash-escape a bare `$` to get a literal `$`: `\$ 100 to \$ 200` becomes \$ 100 to \$ 200 as opposed to $ 100 to $ 200. (Some exceptions do unfortunately apply.)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I didn't realize it was an all-or-nothing thing. I know *strikethrough* doesn't work in comments (for some reason...)

Comment: I voted to close as "too broad".  The impacts of this change will be different depending on the tech level and the scope of the surrounding countryside/nation.  Without these parameters, there's just too many ways this question can go.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to mention if it is medieval (or fantasy) world or modern world.

In first case you have basically removed what humans are spending 99% of their time on. Suddenly everybody would have time to go to elementary school, learn to read and write, and do math. I suspect that such village would be instantly catapulted into renaissance, and soon become powerhouse of medieval world.

On the other hand if you have a "modern" city changes would be different. I would assume that most people are spending around 0% of their time getting water and around 5% of their time preparing food (less if they are students/workers eating at cantine). Hopefully (yeah, I know this isn't true for people working on minimal wage) most people only spend small percent of their money on basic sustenance food. You would need to close cheap supermarkets and kitchens would become something of luxury but nothing major would change.

One note is that intro to economics teaches us that once you reduce price of a good (food and water) prices of complementary goods rise (eg. housing, schools ...). So I wouldn't expect people to be any more well off in this foodless town than in other towns.

Beggars will only come to your city if they don't like begging, and there are theories that most beggars actually either like being beggars (not having to answer to anybody) or are forced into beggary. I don't see why would they in any case flock to your city.

Now, depending on how much you want to go into details you have options:

1. As Will mentioned, just use this infinite amount of food to feed the cows.
2. If you want to be more morbid, and food is magically appearing, you can extract it from stomaches of said cows and sell it. Voila you get free grass you can use for heating.
3. If you are feeling even more morbid, and water is magically appearing in bodies of animals, just put animals on top of very tall building, stick a tube in their stomach and use water dripping out to run a huge hydro-power-plant.
4. If you are feeling silly, have millions of hamsters spin wheels generating electricity.
5. If you are feeling like making dystopia and magic is nourishing without literally creating food and water, you could remove any of pieces needed for converting food into blood sugar (eg. throat) and make people your slaves. If they live town, their bodies will not be able to start producing energy from food and will die, so they must stay in town and do your evil overlords bidding.
6. If your magic affects all living organisms suddenly fish will be able to live in any water, no matter how pure it is. Yeast and rot will live on walls since they don't need food and water.
7. Generally you have broken laws of thermodynamics and conservation of mass and energy, your world is completely broken.

Comment: Ahh the 2nd law of thermodynamics. Most of worldbuilding woudn't exist if we had to follow it strictly.

Answer (score 2):

It would definitely attract the rich, because someone rich would build a wall around it to keep the riffraff out and proceed to run a livestock operation on every square foot of it.

The main expense and hassle of livestock is ensuring their access to food and water.  If that piece is gone and the cattle magically fatten and water themselves it will be like printing money for the owner.

The main problem as I see it would be manure disposal.  Or maybe magic sustenance does not entail heaps of manure?  @Andrew Dodds was wondering about that too.

Comment: Using the towns property to raise live stock would be an brilliant use of this property! Depending on how humane they are I could imagine warehouse (or cellars) full of cattle living on nothing and being harvested for veal.

Comment: Yes; optimal use would be multistory facilities sort of like chicken operations.  No food, no water, no waste, no exercise.  Think how tender that meat would be!

Comment: The question is pretty clearly too broad.  Please help users improve questions before answering.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would attract the poor much more than the rich.

Assuming that the surrounding society is not rich enough that food is abundant and cheap, the poor might seriously struggle with hunger. A place where this problem is solved would be very appealing to the poor. The poorer a person is, the more appealing.

Rich people don't struggle with getting enough to eat, pretty much by definition. Generally, to a rich person the cost of food is trivial. A rich person might find it convenient that he doesn't have to take breaks from whatever work or entertainment he's doing to eat, but that would be the only advantage.

Are people still able to eat if they want to? Lots of people -- myself included -- enjoy eating. People like good tasting food. I often eat when I'm not hungry just because I like food. (Which might have something to do with me being overweight, but that's another story.)

Some people might dislike this phenomenon. If you don't have to eat to live, then your boss might decide that you no longer need a lunch break. Stopping to eat is often a convenient excuse for taking a break from work.

Presumably farmers and butchers and bakers and restaurant owners would not like this at all.

Depending on how much of their income people in this society spend on food, this might free up significant amounts of money for other things. For most of history for most people in the world, a sizable percentage of their income went to buying food. If they don't need to spend money on food, people might suddenly see their income effectively multiplied by 5 or 10 or more.

Similarly, for most of history, most people have been farmers. I read recently that in the United States, the 1870 census was the first time that less than half of the people said their occupation was "farmer". So all these farmers would be freed up for other jobs. Depending on how things worked out, that could be anything from artists and poets to scientists to soldiers to conquer neighboring nations.

Oh, it occurs to me that this would be welcomed by lazy people. Now you don't have to work to live. While presumably you still have to work to have a house and other nice things, some would be happy to do without in exchange for not having to work. Or maybe they'd get just the minimal amount of work needed to afford basic creature comforts. This society would probably have lots of people wandering about doing pretty much nothing. And bored, lazy people often end up in gangs, so there might be more violence and crime.

Comment: I’m under the assumption income usually correlates (to a degree) with cost of living. If workers in this town do not need to eat, I would think employers would try their best to offer less to employees.

Comment: @Madcow Hmm. If workers are producing products that can be sold for, say, 100 foobars per day's output, I'd think the workers could negotiate salaries fairly close to 100 foobars per day, minus cost of raw materials and other expenses, leaving something for profit for the owner. If an employer is unwilling to pay that, some other employer can outbid him and steal his best employees. US salaries haven't gone down as the cost of food has fallen over the last 100 years or so: they've gone up, and very dramatically so.

Comment: The question is pretty clearly too broad. Please help users improve questions before answering.

Comment: @James Hmm, I disagree that the question is too broad. It seems to me to be on the same level as many other questions on this site.

Comment: Anytime a question asks "what is the impact on society" it is too broad.  Answers could cover the military, art, education, politics, finance, in short ANYTHING that makes a society what it is...thus too broad.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot imagine there is one true answer to this. (at least not without fleshing our more of the world and this town)

It would only attract nobility and the rich if it has something else. (They are already rich. Food probably is not a problem, unless food is a problem globally?) Maybe a clever entrepreneur created a luxury resort there, and uses the replenishing quality as a gimmick to attack costumers.

If it did attack nobility one thing to keep in mind, good food taste good. I don’t believe people would purpose go without eating if food was available and it can be afforded. If you are a rich noble, eating food could be a sign of your power.  For the rich eating isn’t about survival in this case It’s about showing your status and enjoying life. Similar concept to the vomitorium of Rome.

It could attract beggars, the poor if the environmental conditions were acceptable. If you can’t afford food then you probably have trouble affording shelter and cloths. Going to a place where you will freeze to death instead of starve isn’t that appealing to me at least.

If the land all around this place is barren, then the town might be a prospering trading post. No reason to go all the way across the deserted waist land when you can buy and sell your goods at this permanent settlement half way. 
There could be to types of individuals who live there. Those who laze about just happy that they can exist without worries of food or water. Taking part time jobs just to pay for rent, and minimal luxuries. Those who work so hard that food and water tend to take back seats. I can easily imagine an eccentric researcher/author working day and night on their project of choice, only taking breaks to sleep living here.

If there is a hospital in this town, the hospital might receive a good amount of attention. Diseases like Cholera tend to kill you via dehydration and can be treated with proper fluids and Electrolyte intake. In this town you would ‘magically’ stay properly hydrated.

Answer (score 0):

### Your economy is going to be different

Much of the economy (both in terms of money and in terms of jobs) revolves around food.

For the USA:

> Agriculture, food, and related industries contributed $992 billion to U.S. gross domestic product (GDP) in 2015, a 5.5-percent share. [...] The overall contribution of the agriculture sector to GDP is larger than this because sectors related to agriculture—forestry, fishing, and related activities; food, beverages, and tobacco products; textiles, apparel, and leather products; food and beverage stores; and food service, eating and drinking places—rely on agricultural inputs in order to contribute added value to the economy. [...] In 2015, 21.0 million full- and part-time jobs were related to the agricultural and food sectors—11.1 percent of total U.S. employment. [...] With a 12.5-percent share, food ranked third behind housing (32.9 percent) and transportation (17 percent) in a typical American household's 2015 expenditures.   [[USDA]](https://www.ers.usda.gov/data-products/ag-and-food-statistics-charting-the-essentials/ag-and-food-sectors-and-the-economy.aspx)

There are a lot more statistics at that site.

Basically, if you're talking about one city, then that city will have to find radical new ways to employ it's people.

1. Your target area no longer needs restaurants. So all those employees are laid off.
2. All those closed restaurants become vacant properties.
3. All that sales tax revenue dries up, too.
4. Grocery stores close. More lost sales tax, more employees out of jobs.
5. No more kitchen appliance stores, etc. either.

So your area will have to find a way to employ those people. Otherwise, they become homeless. Sure, maybe they're well-fed homeless, but homeless nonetheless.

For those not employed in the food industry, the sudden boost to disposable income will be nice. You'd probably see an uptick in non-essential purchases. Amazon boxes for everyone! Maybe this will help offset the tax losses? Not sure. Some of it might go into better savings, retirement planning, and/or debt reduction, too. That'd be nice.

Long-term, the region would completely change the way buildings are produced. If you're not eating, do you still need toilets? You won't need vending machines or break rooms. Homes won't require kitchens. Architects will have a radical influx of new design ideas since so much of a home's space is taken up by food preparation and storage space.

Population changes would occur, but it's difficult to know whether that change would be an influx of wealthy or an influx of lower income brackets. Wealthy people can move easier than poor people. So they have the option to move more readily than lower income brackets. But they also have more flexibility around eating. If we're talking about a city, perhaps they don't mind eating. Maybe they take vacations into the area for the novelty. Or out of the area to enjoy tasting foods and the strange concept of alcohol or sugary treats.

But the poorest people seldom have the option to move. So I don't think you'd see a huge influx of poor people en masse. Perhaps over time, but not as a mass migration event or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention when in time your town exists.  Considering the amount of effort people expend on feeding themselves even today, but especially in ancient history, this town would be a highly sought after commodity.  I believe wars would be fought over it (or at least would have been fought over it).  In ancient times, it most certainly would be run by wealthy and while I do believe it would attract beggars, I believe the ruling class would keep them out so they could profit from it.  If it were in more modern times, I believe that a magical solution would be heavily investigated by scientists/rulers/corporations to figure out how to mass produce the effect.  If the effect is caused by technology, then obviously that wouldn't apply.

As others have mentioned, any food people simply wanted to eat would be grown out of town so as not to waste the space inside of town.  In fact, there might be some kind of lottery put into effect to make use of some of it's benefits.

Hope this helps.